# How to calculate and display column dynamically using Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Datatables to display my data in form of a table .

I was able to form Table using Jquery Datatables  based on existing  javascript resource .

Right now i have got two columns in the table Name and Price .

I need to display a Third column by name SubPrice which is calculated dynamically  based on Total - Price

http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/5/

I was trying it this way , but no luck

```
var table =   $('#kiran').dataTable(
    {
      "order": [
        [1, "desc"]
      ],
      "paging": false,
     "aaData": json,
      "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "Name" },
        { "mDataProp": "Price" },
          { 
     mRender: function(data, type, row){
       return row.Total - row.Price;
     }
    ]

    });
```

Could anybody please help me how to do this

I modified my code to this

```
 var json = [
  {
    "Name": "ONE",
    "Price": "12" ,
    "Total" : "120"
  },
  {
    "Name": "TWO",
    "Price": "100",
     "Total" : "500"
  },
  {
    "Name": "THREE",
    "Price": "42" ,
     "Total" : "300"
  }]




     $(function()
      {
     var table =   $('#kiran').dataTable(
        {
          "order": [
            [1, "desc"]
          ],
          "paging": false,
         "aaData": json,
          "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "Name" },
            { "mDataProp": "Price" },
            { "mDataProp": "My_New_Column_Name" ,
        mRender: function(data, type, row){
        return row.Total - row.Price;
        }
    },
        ]
        })
      })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/7/

I am getting this as part of browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

Comment: It seems that there are some mismatched brackets/braces in your code. Check your browser's console for javascript errors. Also, I think you need to include the `subPrice` column in your `<thead`>.

Comment: I was trying all things but still no luck .

Comment: Did you add the "SubPrice" column to your `<thead>`?

Comment: Ya ,please refer to this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/7/

Comment: In the fiddle, am getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in browser console.

Comment: There is no third column in your `<thead>`.

Comment: "mDataProp": "My_New_Column_Name" , see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cv04pp37/7/

Answer (score 0):

The question is posted on the Datatables forum and there is an answer there: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25675/how-to-display-computed-column-dynamically-using-jquery-datatables#Comment_70573

Here is a copy of that answer:
    I believe he means to do this:

```
Javascript

var table =   $('#kiran').dataTable({
"order": [[1, "desc"]],
"paging": false,
"aaData": json,
"aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "Name" },
    { "mDataProp": "Price" },
    { mRender: function(data, type, row){
        return row.Total - row.Price;
        }
    }
  ]
});
```